# How to take a picture of in panaroma mode?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an application that allow the user to take a picture of text either from android device Gallery or from android Camera application in a Panorama mode .But i can not find any source or tutorial to do this.How can i do this in my application? how to make an application that take picture from android camera application in a panaroma mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read native camera app source code.. and implement same in ur app

Comment: Is it support to integrating this panaroma mode in Android OS 2.3 (Gingerbread)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still actual for you, but hope it will be helpful for someone.

Panorama feature is already implemented in standard android camera at least since Android 4.0 (perhaps it was available in even earlier versions but I'm not sure, you can check it), so since source code is open for everyone, it might be the easiest way just to copy required functionality.

Although you can download source of apps from https://android.googlesource.com/ (you want LegacyCamera or Camera), you can't just open project of any standard app in Eclipse or other IDE. For example, LegacyCamera depends on Gallery2 and other dependences that might be hard to be resolved.

I spent several days trying to move panorama feature to separate project. You can download it from here: https://github.com/yankeppey/PanoramaSample . Several remarks:

1. Functional core (creating one panorama image from several ones, progress notices, etc) is on native part.
2. I used java code from from LegacyCamera which was used in Android 4.0-4.1, not 4.2, because it was significantly easier for me. Native part is taken from 4.2, it has only minor changes inside and almost the same JNI interfaces.
3. This project is just to help you move panorama feature to your own app, it's not like kind of library, don't expect clean code without bugs, it's just pretty dirty and buggy project. If I have time I'll try to make it cleaner, but there is no warranty :)